# Data Validation in google sheet using If condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want conditional data validation.

If the value in H3 or I3 cell is "Yes" then remove the data validation in J3 and L3 cells.
For reference: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aAb8Oi0Fg6e86TtBOpseAWdtKFdFhi4s3N5DpSykuCk/edit#gid=0) is sheet link.
[image]

Comment: In your situation, for example, under the cells "J3" and "L3" has no data validation, when the cells "H3" or "I3" is not "Yes", what result do you want?

Comment: Show data validation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply and your question, by guessing your goal, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your reply, I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the value of the cells "H3" or "I3" is "Yes", you want to remove the data validations of the columns "J" and "L" on the same row.
- When the values of the cells "H3" or "I3" doesn't include "Yes", you want to set the data validations to the columns "J" and "L" on the same row.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

In this sample script, in order to automatically run the script when the columns "H" or "I" are edited, I use the simple trigger of the OnEdit trigger.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save it.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const checkColumns = [8, 9]; // From your question, this script is automatically run, when the columns "H" and "I" are edited.

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Returns" || !checkColumns.includes(range.columnStart) || range.rowStart <= 2) return;
  const row = range.getRow();
  const values = sheet.getRange(`H${row}:I${row}`).getValues()[0];
  const r = sheet.getRangeList(["J", "L"].map(f => `${f}${row}`));
  if (values.includes("Yes")) {
    r.clearDataValidations();
  } else {
    const rules = ["'Data validation'!$J$2:$J$11", "'Data validation'!$L$2:$L$6"];
    r.getRanges().forEach((rr, i) => rr.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(e.source.getRange(rules[i]), true).build()));
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- **When you run this script, please edit the cells of columns "H" and "I". By this, the script is run. When you directly run this script, an error like `Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` because of no event object. Please be careful about this.**
- When this script is run by editing the columns "H" and "I", when the value of "H" or "I" of the edited row includes "Yes", the data validations of the columns "J" and "L" of the same row are removed. On the other hand, when the values of "H" and "I" of the edited row don't include "Yes", the data validations are set to the columns "J" and "L" of the same row.
- If you want to set the data validations when both values of columns "H" and "I" are "No", please modify as follows.

  - From: `} else {`
  - To: `} else if (values.every(f => f == "No")) {`

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)